# How should I set up multiple floating boxes with pictures inside and text around?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a floating box on the right and put a picture inside it.
And I want to paragraph to be on the left of it and - when it's long enough - below the picture too. And additionally to this I want to put another floating box with a picture inside on the left side a bit more downside. And let the text inside the paragraph also go around it.
So first I managed to do now I created the first part with a floating box on the rigt and text around. But how can I put another picture below in a floating box on the left now and address it separately in CSS?

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="picture">
        <h1>this is the first heading</h1>
            <p><img src="Images/car.jpg" alt="car">sample

                <img src="Images/car2.jpg" alt="car2">

            </p>    
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
div.picture img    {
                float: right;
                width: 300px;
                height: 200px;
                }
```

Comment: why you need the div? it seems useless, simply float the image alone

Comment: You're right. It looks the name now without the second div. html: `<body>
        <div class="absatz1">
            <h1>this is the first heading</h1>
                <p>sample</p>

                <img src="Images/car.jpg" alt="car">
        </div>
    </body>`  css: `div.absatz1 img    {
                float: right;
                width: 300px;
                height: 200px;
                }` Is that right this way?

Comment: yes it's right .. if it's working like you want then it's right ;)

Comment: Not exactly how I want it to work, when the text inside the `<p>`gets longer the picture just gets pushed down. How can I fix it on the right side and just make the text inside the paragraph go around it?

Comment: in this case put the image inside the `p` and not outside

Comment: Ok, It works when I put it at first in the paragraph before the text. Does it work also somehow when I put it below the text? And what If I want to put in there another picture. But this time float it on the left. Can you tell me how to address the pictures separately in CSS?

Comment: I am afraid this will turn to a chat discussion which isn't the purpose of comments :) ... you may edit your question to add all those details, then we may add a detailed answer covering everything, it will be more useful ;)

Comment: Ok, I have changed it. Maybe this is now easier to help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that the `<p>` tag is a block-level element, so your floating `<div>` is sitting below it. If you style your paragraph to be `inline-block`, for example, you should get what you're looking for.

But you should be able to just put your `img` directly in your paragraph, and float it to the right, and then the paragraph should flow around the image as necessary.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "inline-block"? You mean to put the picture inside the paragraph?

Comment: `p` tags are block-level by default, meaning they will take up all horizontal space, and push any elements that follow them below them. That is why your `img` was getting pushed below the paragraph initially. You can set a paragraph to `display: inline-block`, just to give an example, and then 2 elements, like a paragraph and an image, would be able to sit next to each other. But...the text wouldn't flow around the image in that case, so it doesn't actually address your issue. I was more pointing out why your image was sitting below the paragraph, despite your `float: right`.

Comment: I've tried this out. And actualy the text flows around the picture with `display: inline-block;` and the picture stays in the horizontal line with the text . I've created a text in the paragraph and put a image in the middle of it. And the text was around the picture. Or maybe I understood this not correctly because I do not see a big change.